# How to extract a set of rows in a dataframe from data in other dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract lines from a data frame containing genome coverage information. I want to extract only the positions of specific genes, I have this information in another data frame.

The data frame with gene information, looks like:

```
df.1 <- data.frame(
  "Gene" = c("UMAG_11067", "UMAG_03291"),
  "Chr" = c(9, 14),
  "Start" = c(18431, 35712),
  "End" = c(21239, 39416),
  "Function" =  c("ROS", "ROS"))
```

```
      Gene Chr Start   End Function
UMAG_11067   9 18431 21239      ROS
UMAG_03291  14 35712 39416      ROS
```

With `pivot_longer` transform the table to create a variable call it **Position**

```
df.1 <- df.1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = Start:End,
               names_to = "StartEnd", 
               values_to = "Position")
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Gene         Chr Function StartEnd Position
  <chr>      <dbl> <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>
1 UMAG_11067     9 ROS      Start       18431
2 UMAG_11067     9 ROS      End         21239
3 UMAG_03291    14 ROS      Start       35712
4 UMAG_03291    14 ROS      End         39416
```

The data frame with the coverage information from the sequencing, looks like:

```
df.coverage <- data.frame(
  "Chr" = c(rep(9, 25000), rep(14, 50000)),
  "Position" = c(seq(1,25000), seq(1, 50000)),
  "Coverage" = c(rep(370, 25000), rep(185,50000)))
```

```
  Chr Position Coverage
    9        1      370
    9        2      370
    9        3      370
   14        1      185
   14        2      185
   14        3      185
```

My desired output is:

```
 Chr Position Coverage
   9    18431      370
   9    18432      370
   9    18433      370
   9    18434      370 # to the end of the gene
   9    21239      370
...
  14    35712      185
  14    35713      185
  14    35714      185
  14    35715      185 # to the end of the gene
  14    39416      185
```

I've tried creating an ID column by concatenating the chr and position columns:

```
df.1$ID <- paste(df.1$Chr, df.1$Position, sep = "-")

df.coverage$ID <- paste(df.coverage$Chr, df.coverage$Position, sep= "-")
```

and then using logical index

```
df.coverage[df.coverage$ID %in% df.1$ID, ]
```

which produce the next output:

```
 Chr Position Coverage       ID
   9    18431      370  9-18431
   9    21239      370  9-21239
  14    35712      185 14-35712
  14    39416      185 14-39416
```

This code only identified the columns where the ID matchs...

How can I subset the data frame with the coverage to extract the coverage of each nt of the target genes?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Its highly recommended to use mature tools for tasks like this, e.g. [bedr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bedr/vignettes/Using-bedr.html#in-Region). There are many edge cases that cannot be foreseen and handled easily.

Comment: This looks like a join task. Question is, which column(s) are shared between the two df? Apparently `Chr`, correct?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Yes, just the **Chr** column is shared.

Comment: You create your ID in `df.1` using a variable called `Position`, but there’s no such variable in `df.1` at the beginning of your post?

Comment: @zephryl it's true! I forgot a step in which I used `pivot_longer` to transform the table and create the variable **Position**

Comment: @zephryl I've corrected the code that I posted

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two steps: first merge in all the positions for each `Chr`, then filter to those between `Start` and `End`. Note this uses your initial, non-pivoted version of `df.1`.

```
library(dplyr)

df.2 <- df.1 %>%
  left_join(df.coverage, by = "Chr") %>%
  filter(Position >= Start & Position <= End) %>%
  select(Chr, Position, Coverage)
  
head(df.2)
```

Output:

```
  Chr Position Coverage
1   9    18431      370
2   9    18432      370
3   9    18433      370
4   9    18434      370
5   9    18435      370
6   9    18436      370
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The code that you provides is working!